# How to Save site as template in Sharepoint On-Premises 2019

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

Save site as template option not shown in Sharepoint 2019 on-premises. Any one help me to sort-out the issue.

Comment: Could you provide more information like what site collection features are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the URL directly?

[site]/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx

Comment: I have the same problem. I can access your URL, but when I try to save I get an error: "Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred." Don't know if it's safe and useful to print the correlation ID here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes dude, Now I can able to save template.

Comment: You should use comments to answer to somebody